# How to set local path for statsd log file configuration

Tags: logging, statsd

How do you set the log file path in the configuration file so that all the incoming messages can be dumped to a file statsd.log for example.

What I have so far is like this but it does not seem to work:

```
{
   graphitePort: 2003,
   graphiteHost: "omitted.for.post.com",
   port: 8125,
   flushInterval: 10000,
   debug: false,
   dumpMessages: true,
   log: "some/file/path/statsd.log"
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output of statsd to wherever you want

```
node /usr/share/statsd/stats.js /etc/statsd/rdioConfig.js 2>&1 >> /tmp/statsd.log
```

Or you can set the logging to go to syslog. https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/exampleConfig.js#L42

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can initialize your own logger with the help of log4js library.

```
var log4js = require(log4js);
log4js.loadAppender('file');
log4js.addAppender(log4js.appenders.file(config.log), 'bekcilog');
var loggerjs = log4js.getLogger('bekcilog')
log4js.replaceConsole(loggerjs);
```

Calling `replaceConsole` method is critical so that all console logs could be caught and dumped into the log file you specified. Because as default, statsd logs on console; you will catch all of them with this way.